# What kind of Java type is "[B"?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, cryptography, md5

I am trying to get MD5 encrypted pass from MySQL DB via Java code (Hibernate). But I cant get neither String nor any reasonable Java type.

The only thing I am getting is this unhelpful message:
**java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.Blob** (or whatever Java type I try cast to).

Here is my method:

```
public void testCrypto() {
        session.beginTransaction();
        // creates native SQL query
        // uses native MySQL's MD5 crypto
        final Blob pass = (Blob) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT MD5('somePass')")
            .list().get(0);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Here is full stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.Blob
    at domain.DatabaseTest.testCrypto(DatabaseTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

That my friend is an array of bytes. In JNI, [B is used to describe an array (`[`) of bytes (`B`). An array of ints is `[I` etc.

You can get a bit more information on field descriptors here:
[JNI Types and Data Structures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html) ([Table 3-2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp276) should be what you are looking for).

Comment: Thank you, you have been most helpful!

Comment: @rfeak the link outdated. Can you post a new link?

Comment: @Kasnady I have fixed the links :)

Answer (score 9):

It's the class name of `byte[].class`. Try this:

```
System.out.println(byte[].class.getName());
```

Output (you guessed it):

> [B

And if you want to access the readable name, use [`Class.getCanonicalName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getCanonicalName%28%29):

```
System.out.println(byte[].class.getCanonicalName());
```

Output:

> byte[]

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers state, that is a byte array.

If you want to get a string from a byte array, use the String constructor:

```
public void testCrypto()
{
        session.beginTransaction();
        // creates native SQL query
        // uses native MySQL's MD5 crypto
        final String pass = new String(session.createSQLQuery("SELECT MD5('somePass')")
            .list().get(0));
        session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Comment: great, but this is really strange behavior! This String is exact same as what prints mysql console. But pass.getBytes().length says its 32, and MD5 should be 128bits. Where did I lost clue?

Comment: @Xorty: There is a difference between measuring encryption strength and the length of a String. MD5 will convert any input to a string that has no more and no less than 32 hex characters.

Answer (score 3):

`[B` is the encoded type name for a byte array (byte[]), which should normally only appear in type signature strings, as its not a valid type name.