# java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, openjpa, blueprint-osgi

I have written an entitity class with Field LoginId and Password.

Iam encrypting the passwrd and stoiring it in the db using the AES_ENCRYPT.

I want to retrive only the password which is decrypted. so, im using AES_DECRYPT using NAtiveQueryis in OPen JPA 2.0.

Query i have written is :

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select AES_DECRYPT(l.password,?2) from loginDetails l where l.loginID = ?1");
q.setParameter(1, loginId);
q.setParameter(2, getKey());
String s = q.getSingleResult();
```

But im getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at com.rcs.chef.validation.UserValidation.decryptedPasswordForID(UserValidation.java:99)
at com.rcs.chef.validation.UserValidation.validateUser(UserValidation.java:81)
at com.rcs.chef.validation.UserValidation.activate(UserValidation.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:226)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:824)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:636)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:724)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:64)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:219)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:147)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:640)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:331)
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:227)
```

I have even tried  this:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select AES_DECRYPT(l.password,?2) from loginDetails l where l.loginID = ?1");
q.setParameter(1, loginId);
q.setParameter(2, getKey());
List<Object> s = q.getResultList();  

String s1 = null;
for(Object o : s){
    s1= (String) o;
}
```

Even here also im gettng the same Exception as :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Object
```

Can you tell me what is the Mistake with the query adn handling the req.

Comment: Why use the database to do that when Java has libraries to do that for you?

Comment: Do not encrypt passwords.  Passwords should be securely _hashed_; it should never be possible to retrieve a password.

Comment: Why use Java libraries when the database provides this out of the box, so that the password doesn't even have to leave the db?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Similar question: [What kind of Java type is "[B"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606864/what-kind-of-java-type-is-b)

MySQL's `AES_DECRYPT` does *not* return a `String` but rather an array of bytes, denoted by "[B". Cast the result to `byte[]` and build your string from that.

It looks like you don't even need to decrypt the password; you just want to `validateUser`, right? - In that case, as others have noted, secure hashes should be used.

You can easily do this with MySQL, as it already provides the necessary [functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1): MD5 (considered insecure), SHA1 (pretty much standard), and SHA2 (even more secure than SHA1).

So your scheme basically may look like:

`insert into loginDetails (..., passwordHashSalt, passwordHash) values ( ..., ?1, SHA1(CONCAT( ?1, ?2 )) )`, where `?1` is set to the unique 'salt', which may be for example the user name itself, and `?2` is the actual password. Note that the salt must be stored in the DB too and 'must' be unique for every user/password; thus, the user name is a natural choice for that.

Then, to verify a given password you can do:

`select 'OK' from loginDetails where ... and passwordHash = SHA1(CONCAT( passwordHashSalt, ?1 ))`, where `?1` is the password which is to be verified.

For more information search the internet for 'password hashing', see for example [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-hash-functions-and-keeping-passwords-safe/) or [here](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Those hashing operations may also be done in your database client code instead, if desired.

Comment: Is encrypting the passwords and saving them using the DB functions not a good desing??